# Exporting ActiveView to Jpeg using ArcGIS 10.2.2 fails

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, vba

I have some legacy VBA code that exports the activeview to a jpeg, which needs to be updated, so it can be used in ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.2. The application uses the following code

```
    Option Explicit
Public Sub ExportToJpeg()
'This will export the current map as a jpeg
    Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
    Set pMxDoc = ThisDocument
    Dim pActiveView As IActiveView
    Set pActiveView = pMxDoc.ActiveView
    Dim strImgFolder As String

    strImgFolder = "C:\Temp"
    'If Dir(strImgFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then
     '   MkDir strImgFolder
    'End If
    'Create an ExportJPEG object and QI the pExport interface pointer onto it.
    ' To export to a format other than JPEG, simply create a different CoClass here
    ' and change the file extension of the ExportFileName.
    Dim pExport As IExport
    Set pExport = New ExportJPEG
    pExport.ExportFileName = strImgFolder & "\" & "aaaa" & ".jpg"

    'Set the export object resolution to 96 dpi.  The default screen resolution for
    ' MS Windows is usually 96dpi, and this value is also the default resolution for all
    ' of the ArcGIS image format exporters.  The vector format exporters (PDF, AI, etc.)
    ' default to 300 dpi, so we should explicitly set resolution here to be certain we
    ' are working with a resolution of 96.
    pExport.Resolution = 96

    'For both PageLayout and Map objects, the ExportFrame property always holds a tagRECT
    ' structure appropriate for exporting.  The values in the tagRECT correspond to the width
    ' and height to export, measured in pixels with an origin in the top left corner.
    Dim exportRECT As tagRECT
    exportRECT = pActiveView.ExportFrame

    'Create a new envelope object and populate it with the values from exportRECT.
    ' We need to do this because the exporter object requires an envelope object
    ' instead of a tagRECT structure.
    Dim pPixelBoundsEnv As IEnvelope
    Set pPixelBoundsEnv = New Envelope
    pPixelBoundsEnv.PutCoords exportRECT.Left, exportRECT.Top, exportRECT.Right, exportRECT.bottom

    'Assign the envelope object to the exporter object's PixelBounds property.  The exporter object
    ' will use these dimensions when allocating memory for the export file.
    pExport.PixelBounds = pPixelBoundsEnv

    'Initialize the exporter object and store it's device context in the hDC variable.  At this method
    ' call, the exporter object will create an empty file and allocate memory based on resolution,
    ' bit depth, and pixel bounds.
    Dim hDC    As Long
    hDC = pExport.StartExporting

    'Redraw the active view, rendering it to the exporter object device context instead of the app display.
    'We pass the following values:
    ' * hDC is the device context of the exporter object.
    ' * pExport.Resolution is 96, the default resolution value for all image export formats.  Default screen
    ' resolution for MS Windows is usually 96dpi.
    ' * exportRECT is the tagRECT structure that describes the dimensions of the view that will be rendered.
    ' The values in exportRECT should match those held in the exporter object's PixelBounds property.
    pActiveView.Output hDC, pExport.Resolution, exportRECT, Nothing, Nothing

    'Finish writing the export file and cleanup any intermediate files.
    pExport.FinishExporting
    pExport.Cleanup

End Sub
```

Which I got from here http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/Samples/Cartography/Printing_and_Exporting/ExportActiveView.htm , it works perfectly in Desktop 10.0 but not in 10.2.2

Does anyone know how to get the above code working in 10.2.2?

EDIT -
Should have mentioned, no error occurs, The code runs to the end, a JPEG is exported but it is blank with no data, even though there is data within the map.

Comment: What error do you get? Did you install the VBA license?
http://support.esri.com/em/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/42322

Comment: Yep, VBA licence is installed. There is no error (i should have mentioned this).. But all i get is a blank jpeg, with no map.

Comment: Does c:\temp exist?, this was mandatory on Windows XP and previous but was discontinued in Vista and beyond, also UAC (if you haven't got frustrated with it and turned it off) may be preventing you from writing to your C drive (thanks again Microsoft!) in a *special* folder. Try setting strImgFolder to a folder that you know to exist and have write permissions to. This looks very similar to code I've ripped off myself a few years ago; nothing else is obviously wrong. Consider downloading Visual Studio Express (free) and using VB.net and EsriAddins, VBA is in its final death throws.